# vba al insertar un valor redondea los números grandes

Tags: vba

Estoy tratando de hacer una operación muy simple, que es copiar un dato de una celda a otra en excel por vba.
El caso es que son números grandes, y al insertar el valor en la celda, redondea las últimas cifras.

Por ejemplo: 1234567891234567 me lo transforma en 1234567891234570

¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por curiosidad, por que has quitado el único código que tenias en tu pregunta?

Comment: Porque parece que no tenía nada que ver, en principio pensaba que era por el formato, pero no, es solamente al pasar el valor, de un cell.value a otro.

Comment: @JCstdio puedes añadir el código para ver cómo lo haces? Al ser un valor tan grande debes guardarlo en variables de Texto, ya que las variables de número no son capaces de almacenar semejante número.

Comment: Básicamente es esto: sheet_summary.Cells(f_row_summary, summ_serial_num_column).Value = sheet_licenses.Cells(i, serial_num_column).Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por los límites del propio Excel.

> **[Especificaciones y límites de Excel](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/especificaciones-y-l%C3%ADmites-de-excel-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)**

En el enlace que he puesto, viene una parte que justo explica lo que te pasa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al meter el dígito número 16, incluso aplicando formato numérico, Excel lo va a ignorar, debido a los límites del propio programa.

En tu ejemplo dices que `1234567891234567`, que justo tiene 16 dígitos, lo redondea a `1234567891234570`. Mantiene los 16 dígitos, pero a partir del 16 en adelante son ceros.

La única solución si necesitas que se muestre tal cual, es como han comentado antes, metiendo un apóstrofe (comilla simple) antes del número. De esa manera, Excel lo reconocerá como texto, y podrás visualizarlo.

Si necesitas ese número tan grande para hacer cálculos matemáticos, quizás necesites con otro programa, porque Excel se te queda chico. Si es solo para mostrarlo porque sea, por ejemplo, un código o algún tipo de identificador, entonces puedes usar lo del apóstrofe, que no te afectará a la formulación.

Aun cuando pongas `'1234567891234567` en una celda, para Excel dentro solo habrá un **texto** que pone `1234567891234567`, la comilla no te estorba para nada, porque Excel la ignora a efectos de formulación.

Comment: Si, es básicamente para un reporte, y lo único que tienen que ver es el número en la celda, ni cálculos, ni nada.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que aplicarle un formato numérico a las celdas/rango que desees.

Por ejemplo

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("D").NumberFormat = "########################"
```

Aunque puede que la mejor opción sea formatear la celda como texto:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("D").NumberFormat = "@"
```

Comment: Ya tiene el formato aplicado, el caso es que, lo cojo de un Cell().Value, y lo inserto en otro, tal que sheet.cells(r,c),Value = otra_sheet.cells(r,c),Value. He probado a guardar el valor en una variable, y lo guarda bien, es en el momento de meterlo en la otra cell donde redondea.

Comment: Pon el formato a la celda de destino: `otra_sheet.cells(r,c).NumberFormat = "########################"`

Comment: No, parece que lo sigue redondeando. Tanto si lo formateo antes de meter el valor, como si lo formateo después. Me han dado una solución, pero es un poco chapucera, que sería insertar un apóstrofe (') delante del número. Funciona, pero el apóstrofe queda ahí.

Comment: Entonces puedes formatear la celda como texto: `otra_sheet.cells(r,c).NumberFormat = "@"`